# JavaScript (retrieve data from HTML)

Tags: javascript

I was trying to retrieve some data from a website (HTML) with JavaScript (node.js). The data I want to retrieve is in a paragraph but the whole paragraph is separated by line breaks and my code only fetch the last paragraph.
I am using this codes

```
event.Description = $(this)[0]['next'];
```

How do I get the full paragraph that are broken with line breaks?

```
var request = require("request");
var cheerio = require("cheerio");
var currentDate = new Date();
var url = "westernsydney.edu.au/observatorypenrith/penrith_observatory/…";
request(url, function (err, responce, html) {
if (!err) {
    var $ = cheerio.load(html);
    var eventList = new Array();
    $('div#content table>thead>tr ').each(function (index, item) {

        if (index > 0) {
            var event = {
                Date: null,
                EventName: null,
                Description: null,
                LinkURL: null,
                Year: currentDate.getFullYear()
            };
            var child = $(this).children();
            $(child).each(function (index2) {
                var subChildren = $(this).children();
                $(subChildren).each(function (index3) {
                    if (index2 == 0) {
                        //console.log('Date -', $(this).text()); 
                        event.Date = $(this)[0]['next']['data']
                    } else if (index2 == 1) {
                        event.EventName = $(this).text();
                    } else if (index2 == 2) {
                        event.Description = $(this)[0]['next']['data'];
                    } else if (index2 == 3) {
                        event.LinkURL = $(this).attr('href');
                    }
                });
            });
            eventList.push(event);
        }
    });
    console.log("Events Array", eventList);
}
});
```

Comment: Where do you create the `event`, where did you declare that variable? Currently your code is always writing properties on the very same object, no wonder you only get to see that last result.

Comment: $('div#content table>thead>tr ').each(function(index, item){

            if(index > 0) {
                var event = {
                    Date: null,
                    EventName: null,
                    Description: null,
                    LinkURL: null,
                    Year: currentDate.getFullYear()
                };

Comment: this is the part were i declared my event.

Comment: Its right after the new eventlist variable

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include it in the code

Comment: I have edited the code and added the event

Comment: If you loop over child elements and fill the event with values inside that loop, then pushing that event onto your array should probably happen inside that loop as well, and not after it. (Although you might have to put the initialisation of the `event` object inside that loop as well, otherwise you might be pushing references only, so that even if you have multiple entries in your array afterwards, they still all point to the last "version" of the object.)

Comment: i actually didnt understand how to do it..is it possible to give me some example